# What's the wisest way to detect if a visitor has scrolled to a certain point in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I've looked at this:

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#about

and would like to incorporate a similar idea into a plugin I have. Waypoints looks intriguing but perhaps more than what I need. I'm also wanting to trigger an alert (or similar) when a certain point on the page is reached.

Truth be told, this is related to Google Analytics and getting more accurate bounce rates. I'll spare you the particulars for now but my presumption is that if the visitor scrolls to certain spot on the page and then leaves before visiting any other page that such single page visit is not a real bounce. That is, they interacted with the page. It wasn't glance and go.

I have a plugin for GA and would like to integrate this idea of scrolling and/or reaching a particular spot on the page to be an event that can be tracked. But I'm casting a new for insight before I jump in and get my hands dirty.

Finally, I'm still pretty new to this so please explain clearly and if possible provide links that would lead to my further education.

Comment: You could look at the code of the plugin and extract the part that's interesting for you? You can bind a function to the scroll event, and check the scroll value (the scroll event is fired a lot of times, so you may want to check the scroll value once every X ms at most)

Comment: @Robin - Thanks. The polling every X ms is a good idea. Might you be able to point me to a tut on that?

Comment: I did not really meant "polling every X ms". I meant that if the event is fired 100 times a second, then you would not want to check the position 100 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if the user has scrolled with the `scroll` event...

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    // Scrolled.
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa92e/).

```
// jQuery
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // Scrolled.
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZDnJ/).

...and you can tell *where* they have scrolled with `document.body.scrollTop` and `document.body.scrollLeft`.

```
var body = document.body,
    scrollTop = body.scrollTop,
    scrollLeft = body.scrollLeft;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zEPN/).

```
// jQuery
var body = $('body'),
    scrollTop = body.scrollTop(),
    scrollLeft = body.scrollLeft();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhszR/).

Comment: Thanks Alex. As luck would have it, I found scroll() and scrollTop() after I posted the question. Might you have any ideas on picking up scroll speed? In other words, flying past something while scrolling is now the same as inching down the page, eh?

Comment: @ChiefAlchemist You could use a timeout on the `scroll` event which gets the delta of distance scrolled. If it's beyond some threshold, you could assume the user scrolled fast.